# iterative lengthening pseudo code for traversal of all the nodes

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, robotics

What would the algorithm, pseudo code or actual code to traverse all the nodes in a graph using an iterative lengthening depth-first approach?

Answer (score 1):

I give you first the depth-first pseudo-code for graph

```
DLS(node, goal, depth, visited) 
{
  if ( depth >= 0 ) 
    {
    if ( node == goal )
      return node

    visited.insert(node)

    for each child in expand(node)
      if (child is not in visited)
          DLS(child, goal, depth-1, visited)
  }
}
```

and the iterative DLS is

```
IDDFS(start, goal)
{
  depth = 0
  while(no solution)
  {
    visited = [] // <-- Empty List
    solution = DLS(start, goal, depth,visited)
    depth = depth + 1
  }
  return solution
}
```

You can always transform a graph in a tree by removing graph loop with a *visited list*. :)

Comment: It's important to note that each call to DLS in the iterative-deepening routine starts with a **fresh** closed list; otherwise, the second and later calls would not search at all.

Comment: the answer is not about iterative lenghtening and your descriptions dont match the code that you've given, or am I wrong?

Comment: Isn't the whole point of the IDDFS to not use a list of visited nodes?